# AWS CodePipeline: How to pass output from CloudFormation action to a CodeBuild action

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have an AWS CodePipeline defined in a CloudFormation template.

One of the steps of the pipeline is a CloudFormation action that builds a test environment for my application. The URL of the app's Elastic Load Balancer is one of the outputs defined in this template.

How do I access this output, so that I can use it in the next step, which is a CodeBuild action that will run api tests against the test environment?

I can specify an `OutputFileName` in the CloudFormation Deploy step, but the CodeBuild step would then need 2 input artifacts, the test code and the CloudFormation output file, and there is a maximum of 1 input artifact.

I thought that I could have a step that pushes the CloudFormation output file to S3, so that the api test step can then access it (or simply push it to S3 as part of the CloudFormation::Init code), but I am hoping for something more simple that I could configure in the CodePipeline steps (similar to !ImportValue in CloudFormation).

I also thought that I could assign a 'test url' e.g. http://test.myapp.com, in the CloudFormation step so that the api tests are always run against that specific url, which would be a great option, except that I am spinning up the test environment dynamically just before the tests (because I don't want the cost of it always running), and I'm not sure that the DNS will have propagated by the time the api tests start running.

Thanks in advance

*Definition of CodePipeline CloudFormation action that spins up test environment*

```
...
Name: DeployApplicationInfra
ActionTypeId:
  Category: Deploy
  Owner: AWS
  Version: 1
  Provider: CloudFormation
Configuration:
  ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
  Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
  OutputFileName: test-application-infra-stack.outputs.json
  StackName: test-application-infra-stack
  RoleArn: !Ref CloudFormationServiceRoleArn
  TemplateConfiguration: AppInfraCfnTemplate::test-application-infra.config.json
  TemplatePath: AppInfraCfnTemplate::application-infra.yml
InputArtifacts:
  - Name: AppInfraCfnTemplate
OutputArtifacts:
  -  Name: TestApplicationInfraStackOutputs
```

*Definition of CodePipeline CodeBuild action to run api tests*

```
...
Name: RunApiTests
ActionTypeId:
  Category: Test
  Owner: AWS
  Version: 1
  Provider: CodeBuild
Configuration:
  ProjectName: !Ref ApiTestsBuildProject
InputArtifacts:
  - Name: AppSource

...
ApiTestsBuildProject:
  Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
  Properties:
    Name: companyinsight-api-tests-build
    Artifacts:
      Type: CODEPIPELINE
    Environment:
      ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
      Image: aws/codebuild/nodejs:8.11.0
      Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
    ServiceRole: !Ref CIServerBuildRoleArn
    Source:
      Type: CODEPIPELINE
      BuildSpec: !Sub |
        version: 0.2
        env:
          variables:
            BASE_URL: <Want to inject test app url here!!!>
        phases:
          install:
            commands:
              - npm install
          build:
            commands:
              - npm run api-test
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS CodePipeline: Get CloudFormation outputs in CodeBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983901/aws-codepipeline-get-cloudformation-outputs-in-codebuild)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no workaround to allow 2 input artifacts for CodeBuild from CodePipeline currently.

The alternative I'd recommend for now is to call [aws cloudformation describe-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) from the CLI in your build process and pull the ELB hostname from your stack outputs.

Answer (score 5):

Check this update from AWS https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/aws-codebuild-adds-ability-to-create-build-projects-with-multiple-input-sources-and-output-artifacts/
Seems like you can do t now.