# AWS CodePipeline: Get CloudFormation outputs in CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm learning some DevOps techniques using AWS CodePipeline (Cloudformation and CodeBuild).

My (simplified) pipeline is this:

1. Push to github repo triggers pipeline
2. CloudFormation builds/updates backend infrastructure
3. CodeBuild does some additional work

At the moment, CloudFormation outputs the following:

```
Outputs:
  RestApiId:
    Value: !Ref ApiGateway
    Description: 'API Id'
```

**Question:** How can I get the ApiGateway ID in CloudBuild?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html

You can specify CodePipeline step like this (from documentation):

```
- Name: CreateTestStackA
  Actions:
    - Name: CloudFormationCreate
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Deploy
        Owner: AWS
        Provider: CloudFormation
        Version: '1'
      Configuration:
        ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
        Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
        OutputFileName: TestOutput.json
        RoleArn: !GetAtt [CFNRole, Arn]
        StackName: StackA
        TemplateConfiguration: TemplateSource::test-configuration.json
        TemplatePath: TemplateSource::teststackA.yaml
      InputArtifacts:
        - Name: TemplateSourceA
      OutputArtifacts:
        - Name: StackAOutput
      RunOrder: '1'
```

So in `Configuration` you need to add `OutputFileName` parameter and specify output artifact name. Then you can use that artifact as an input to CodeBuild. In output file (TestOutput.json) you will have a dictionary where key is output name and value is output value.

Comment: Is there any way I can include all files in CloudFormations output? 
This is done in CodeBuild with artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'

Comment: What do you mean by "all files"? CloudFormation action deploys only single stack and saves its output as JSON file. That file may be an input to another action.

Comment: Im using a code pipeline. Next step after CloudFormation is another CodeBuild (can only take one input artifact).

Comment: I need to pass the  input CloudFormation got PLUS the output generated by CloudFormation

Comment: I've solved such issues with Invoke action (Lambda). Create Lambda function (here is an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html) and invoke it with two input artifacts. Such Lambda will then merge those artifacts into one and output it.
It's a bit complex however I couldn't find any better solution.

Comment: I’ve already started on that solution, had hoped for a better solution since this use case must be common. Thanks!